# Issue with returning a char* which is a struct

Tags: c++, struct, char

I am new to C++, and I am trying to return the struct declared within a class via char*.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <cstring>

class test
{
public:
    struct pair
    {
        int a,b;
    };
    test(){
        pir=new pair;
        pir->a=1;
        pir->b=2;
    }

    void readx(char* str)
    {
        char* str2=new char[sizeof(pair)+1];
        str2=reinterpret_cast<char*>(pir);
        strncpy(str,str2,sizeof(pair));
    }
private:
    pair* pir;

};

int main()
{
    test t;
    char* ptr;
    t.readx(ptr);
    cout<<*((int*)ptr)<<endl;
    cout<<*((int*)ptr+4)<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I have tried multiple ways but still failed to return a char* that can be reinterpreted into the struct. Actually the returned char* can only hold the first parameter, losing information about the second parameter, despite that I have used strncpy function. The output of this test code is

```
1
0
```

How could I return the everything about struct within the class?

Comment: `strncpy()` is for copying NUL-terminated string. Try using `memcpy()` instead.

Comment: @MikeCAT I just tried `memcpy()`, but it seemed that it doesn't work either.

Comment: combined with changes with memcpy and +1, it really worked! Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got serious problems with your code. If it's really working, it's working only by accident.

1. Whether it's `strncpy` or `memset` you use it doesn't matter too much because you are passing unitialized pointer to the functions which writes to it:

   ```
   char* ptr;
   t.readx(ptr);
   ```

   Where does `ptr` point to? It may point almost anywhere and using it as `memcpy` target is unpredictable. If you are not very unlucky, you will get a segfault/access violation.
2. Your `readx` method does some crazy thing:

   ```
   char* str2 = new char[sizeof(pair)+1];
   str2 = reinterpret_cast<char*>(pir);
   ```

   Here you first alocate some storage and assign its address to `str2` then you re-assign it to address of `pir`. You can never `delete[]` memory allocated by `new[]` so you introduce a memory leak.
3. Constructor of class `test` allocates memory using `new` but you don't have corresponding destructor calling `delete` -> memory leak.

Then there is your `ptr+4` problem which was already pointed by the others. Here you can find the code corrected to the point where you can expect it to do what you want.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

class test
{
public:
    struct pair
    {
        int a, b;
    };

    test() : pir{ new pair() }
    {
        pir->a = 1;
        pir->b = 2;
    }

    ~test() { delete pir; }

    void readx(char* str)
    {
        memcpy(str, reinterpret_cast<char*>(pir), sizeof(pair));
    }
private:
    pair* pir;
};

int main()
{
    test t;
    char* ptr = new char[sizeof(test::pair)];
    t.readx(ptr);

    cout << *((int*)ptr) << endl;
    cout << *((int*)ptr + 1) << endl;

    delete[] ptr;

    return 0;
}
```

When you understand the basic issues your code have read about the rule of five. For the `test` class you would add something like this:

```
#include <algorithm>

class test
{
    //...

    test(test const& other) : pir{ new pair() }
    {
        pir->a = other.pir->a;
        pir->b = other.pir->b;
    }

    test& operator=(test const& other)
    {
        test copy(other);
        swap(*this, copy);
        return *this;
    }

    test(test&& other) noexcept : pir{ nullptr }
    {
        swap(*this, other);
    }

    test& operator=(test&& other) noexcept
    {
        swap(*this, other);
        return *this;
    }

    friend void swap(test& lhs, test& rhs)
    {
        std::swap(lhs.pir, rhs.pir);
    }
};
```

Comment: Don't forget the rule of 3 (or 5 since C++11).

Comment: @O'Neil added some code related to the rule of five.

Comment: I could never expect a better answer! Really thanks for these elaborations while I am still quite confused about the code in the last part. I will check rules of five immediately. Thank you again for your help!

Answer (score 3):

```
cout<<*((int*)ptr+4)<<endl;
```

This line should be:

```
cout<<*((int*)ptr+1)<<endl;
```

Because you have convert `ptr` to `int *`, which `+1` means move pointer to next 4 bytes (size of int is 4).

Comment: combined with changes with  `memcpy` and `+1`, it really worked! Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

You are incrementing the int pointer by 4. This points 4 integers ahead. That's not what you want.

```
cout<<*((int*)ptr+1)<<endl;
```

That should get you b.